# Bind the values of a grid record to a form and a window

Tags: extjs, bind, extjs5

Although there are several ways to load the values of a record into a form within a window, in the specific case of using binding from a grid to a form (for example, to display the detail of the record) how to bind the same values to a form within a window (for example: to edit the record)?

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1stv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the record in as part of the VM data:

```
var janela = Ext.create('APP.MyWindow', {
    animateTarget: btn.getEl(),
    viewModel: {
        data: { users: selectedRow }
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. Your solution helps a lot and simplifies these cases very much.